# zoom vs background-size in image-sprites in css

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
.svg-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  zoom: 0.65;

  &.dribbble      { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); }
  &.email         { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); }
  &.facebook      { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); }
```

I have svg-icons of various social media sites on my blog. Using the zoom property gives me exactly what I want which is a resized svg-icon. But why does the background-size property not work? When I create a background-size property of less than 100%, the icons multiply and give me minimized, repeating icons?

Comment: background-size: cover /background-repat:no-repeat; ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaYaMG  zoom:0.65; use to be old IES scale propertie

Comment: I see... so background-size repeats by default?